# javaee, Weblogic, LDAP authenticator

Tags: jakarta-ee, ldap, weblogic

I configure a LDAP authenticator with WebLogic as follows:
Weblogic console -> security realms -> myrealm -> providers -> new -> type: ActiveDirectoryAuthenticator...
and set User Name Attribute = sAMAccountName. 
then, my application gets the sAMAccountName of the authenticated user by calling httpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal.getName().

however, this returns just the string (the sAMAccountName).
Is it possible to get the complete LDAP account of the authenticated user (javax.naming.directory.SearchResult, or similar) 
directly from httpServletRequest?

ps: I am aware that I could use an extra LDAP query based on sAMAccountName to get the complete LDAP account of the user,
but this would require an unnecessary second LDAP query, and also to replicate the LDAP configuration from Weblogic into my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OPSS User & Role APIs. They will work with Active Directory.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10043/devuserole.htm#BABBIGAJ

You can query the identity store directly for a specific user or role using the searchUser and searchRole APIs:

`IdentityStore.searchUser(String name);`

`IdentityStore.searchUser(Principal principal);`